# Solution as the real part of complex exponential for simple harmonic motion

Tags: classical-mechanics

Reading through the "Solution as the real part of complex exponential" section of the John Taylor textbook on classical mechanics, I noticed the following :

$x(t) = C_{1}e^{i\omega t} + C_{1}^*e^{-i\omega t}$ 
It is then claimed that 
$x(t) = 2 Re(C_{1}e^{i \omega t })$

I get that this is a result of the fact that for a complex number z, 
$z + z^* = 2 Re(z)$

However, how are we able to apply it to x(t)? Would we not run into some difficulties as $C_{1}$
and $C_{1}^*$ are multiplied by $e^{i \omega t }$ and $e^{-i \omega t }$

Even when I tried to set C1 as a + bi and tried foiling the expression out I could not see how we would arrive at $x(t) = 2 Re(C_{1}e^{i \omega t })$

Comment: Note that $(C_1 e^{i \omega t})^* = C_1^* e^{-i\omega t}$.  Do you see why?

Answer (score 0):

Let us set $ z(t) = \left(C_{1} e^{i \omega t}\right)$. Also, as stated by @Michael Seifert
$$ \left(C_{1} e^{i \omega t}\right)^{*}=C_{1}^{*} e^{-i \omega t}$$
and therefore
$$ x(t) = z(t) + z^{*}(t) $$
But as you yourself stated that $z+z^{*}=2 \operatorname{Re}(z)$, therefore
$$ x(t) = 2Re(z) .$$ Which means
$$ x(t)=2 \operatorname{Re}\left(C_{1} e^{i \omega t}\right)$$

**To see why** $ \left(C_{1} e^{i \omega t}\right)^{*}=C_{1}^{*} e^{-i \omega t}$, let us set $C_1 = a + ib$. Then

\begin{align}
C_{1} e^{i \omega t} &= ae^{i \omega t} + ibe^{i \omega t} \\
& = a(\cos{\omega t} + i\sin{\omega t}) + iab(\cos{\omega t} + i\sin{\omega t}) \\
& = (a\cos{\omega t} - ab \sin{\omega t}) \quad + \quad i(a \sin{\omega t} + ab \cos{\omega t}) 
\end{align}

So
\begin{align}
 \left(C_{1} e^{i \omega t}\right)^{*} & = (a\cos{\omega t} - ab \sin{\omega t}) \quad - \quad i(a \sin{\omega t} + ab \cos{\omega t})   \\
& = a(\cos{\omega t} - i\sin{\omega t}) \quad - \quad iab(\cos{\omega t} - i\sin{\omega t}) \\
& = ae^{-i \omega t} - ibe^{-i \omega t} \\
& = (a - ib)e^{-i \omega t} \\
& = C_{1}^{*} e^{-i \omega t}
\end{align}